# Return true from event handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm calling this factory function in Angular, passing in a percentage value as a parameter:

```
if(scroll_factory.fetch(50)) {
 // If the user has scrolled 50% of page height, do something.
};

scroll_factory.$inject = ['$window', '$document'];
function scroll_factory($window, $document) {

    var factory = {
        fetch: fetch,
        fetch_position: fetch_position
       }

    return factory;



function fetch(percent) {
    $document.on('scroll', fetch_position)

    function fetch_position() {
        var window_inner_height = $window.innerHeight;
        var y = pageYOffset;
        var percentage = (y / window_inner_height) * 100;

        if (percentage > percent) {
            // Condition true - return true for the outer fetch.
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

What I want is for the fetch function to return true when the scroll condition is true.  Thanks.

Comment: `fetch_position` isn't in javascript scope anywhere outside of `fetch()`.

Comment: If all you want is true/false...why bind factory function to scroll handler in the first place. You can't return from an event handler. Really not clear what you are trying to do overall.

Comment: Note to `Return true from event handler function` [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:beforeunloadevent) In general, returning a value from event handler does have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work. In:

```
if(scroll_factory.fetch(50)) { ... }
```

you are already evaluating (the function returns a value a this point) the `fetch` function.

You need to rethink that the `fetch_position` callback is continuously evaluated.

You want to have a scroll-spy functionality as a separated module?

```
.factory('ScrollSpy', function($document, $window) {
  return function(callback) {
    $document.on('scroll', function(e) {
      var y = ...
      if ( y > 123)
        callback(y);
    })
  };
})
```

One way to solve this is to provide a factory which accepts a callback which can be evaluated depending on your demands.

I made a small example, hope it helps: http://plnkr.co/edit/du3dpMlaKYZFuy8WA0QL?p=preview